# file names uses utf8

Tags: utf-8, batch-file, file-rename

I have a text file named rename.txt as follows:

```
34aa85ff2fb46b29fba2283a7b889480306295.flv|بسوی-زیبایی.flv
bb32ca4604217660ab7b6df3938cd0df306294.flv|صدای-تو.flv
b4b802c0182ebfd4fbba9c5ad2ab3904306286.flv|بسوی-حق.flv
```

when i used `bulk rename utility` to rename flv files on the left of the `|` to the corresponding ones to the right i got:

[image: bulk rename utility scshot]

[image: bulk rename result]

Then I tried using a batch file to rename files but the same problem in the cmd:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (rename.txt) do (
  echo %%a
)
pause
```

cmd output:

[image: cmd output]

Note: i can rename the files manually in windows:

[image: expected result]

How can i get the expected result guys?

Comment: Perhaps the text file isn't being recognised as utf8-encoded text. Could it perhaps lack the signature at the beginning? Do the names show correctly when you open the file in `notepad`?

Comment: @AndriyM yes they show correctly in the notepad

Comment: chcp 65001 with lucida console font doesn't work either the rename.txt file is n UTF-8 encoding, I don't know what's missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 65001
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a IN (rename.txt) DO (
  RENAME "%%a" "%%b"
)
```

Make sure that the text file (`rename.txt`) *doesn't* contain the UTF-8 signature (otherwise called [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), BOM) at the beginning, because the `FOR /F` command tries to treat it as a character and attaches it to the first file's name. As a result the first file doesn't get renamed (but all others do).

If you can't get rid of the BOM, just put an empty line at the beginning, so that the BOM stays on that line while other lines, which contain the names, remain "clean". If you add that empty line and do not change the above script, it will produce an error when trying to process the empty line. It shouldn't be a problem, but if you would like to eliminate it, you could do it like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 65001
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%a IN (rename.txt) DO (
  IF NOT "%%b" == "" RENAME "%%a" "%%b"
)
```

Comment: No, I couldn't either. I guess displaying Unicode in cmd is a separate issue from reading/processing Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't use UTF-8, it uses UTF-16LE. Transcode your input file.

Comment: would u please elaborate more

Comment: how can i do it in php? UTF-8 to UTF-16LE conversion?

Comment: thanks. after the conversion i got some Chinese like characters so then what's the code page for utf-16le?

Comment: @pouya: Here you can find the names of the code pages accepted by `iconv` (if that's what you were trying to convert with): http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/

Comment: according to [MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332097(v=vs.71).aspx) the codepage for UTF-16LE is 1200 but i recieve invalid code page error after chcp 1200